# Flat application log view in GCP Stackdriver Logging (springboot app)

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, slf4j

We want to run our Spring-Boot based rest backend in Googles App-Engine, standard environment. Everything is working fine, except for the logging. We can't find a "flat" view of all our application logs. We find our application logs grouped in log `request_log`.

We are logging with SLF4J (with help of lomboks @Slf4j annotation, but that shouldn't matter).

We've tried to follow this [Google How-to Guide](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java) in order to setup a Logback appender for Stackdriver Logging.

1. Adding the mentioned Maven Dependency.
2. Setting up a logback.xml configuration.

Now, the application doesn't properly start anymore. Upon the first request, we only get the following log statements under the respective `request_log` entry.

```
2018-11-05 13:27:54.726 MEZ
[h~<google-project-id>/<instance-id>].<stderr>: SLF4J: A number (121) of logging calls during the initialization phase have been intercepted and are

2018-11-05 13:27:54.726 MEZ
[h~<google-project-id>/<instance-id>].<stderr>: SLF4J: now being replayed. These are subject to the filtering rules of the underlying logging system.

2018-11-05 13:27:54.726 MEZ
[h~<google-project-id>/<instance-id>].<stderr>: SLF4J: See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#replay

2018-11-05 13:27:55.399 MEZ
[h~<google-project-id>/<instance-id>].<stdout>: 

2018-11-05 13:37:42.166 MEZ
[h~<google-project-id>/<instance-id>].<stdout>:   .   ____          _            __ _ _

2018-11-05 13:37:42.320 MEZ
[h~<google-project-id>/<instance-id>].<stdout>:  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \

2018-11-05 13:37:42.321 MEZ
[h~<google-project-id>/<instance-id>].<stdout>: ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \

2018-11-05 13:37:42.834 MEZ
Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.apphosting.runtime.HardDeadlineExceededError: This request (00000166e3d7f348) started at 2018/11/05 12:27:52.520 UTC and was still executing at 2018/11/05 12:37:42.812 UTC.
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:469)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:76)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:62)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingImpl.flush(LoggingImpl.java:544)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingImpl.write(LoggingImpl.java:526)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender.append(LoggingAppender.java:201)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender.append(LoggingAppender.java:63)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:84)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:51)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:270)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:257)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:421)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.log(Logger.java:765)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.NullSandboxPlugin$LogStream.flush(NullSandboxPlugin.java:604)
    at java.io.PrintStream.flush(PrintStream.java:338)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.NullSandboxPlugin$LogPrintStream.println(NullSandboxPlugin.java:468)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringBootBanner.printBanner(SpringBootBanner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationBannerPrinter.print(SpringApplicationBannerPrinter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.printBanner(SpringApplication.java:563)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:135)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.startWebapp(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doStart(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:243)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:181)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:109)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:699)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:661)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:631)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:825)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:273)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It seems, as Spring-Boot isn't able to startup properly. What are we missing?

Comment: Is your issue solved now?
If no, I have some questions. 

1. I understand that you are using Maven and App Engine Standard? Or it is Flexible? 
2. [Did your build logs showed any errors during app deployment?](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/view-build-results). 
3. Did you try to deploy App with SLF4J disabled?